# Is there any reason why operators leave a space at the bottom of the boarded doors?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

[image]

In Rainbow 6 Siege, operators always leave a space at the bottom of boarded doors, a space that is just good enough for a drone to go through.

I'm not asking why in a gameplay perspective it's there (if it wasn't, drones could not go in, removing the point of the drone)

But is there an explanation in game, or in the real life equivalent, why obviously trained agents would leave such a mistake in their boarding up?

Comment: I think it's every time its blocking a door. Windows dont have that space

Comment: And that board is always removed. It's not removed by action of a player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there is a lore reason, but the small gap beneath the door can be tactically advantageous to defenders.

In order to place a breaching charge on the door, attackers must walk up to the door and stand still as they attach the charge. A defender can watch for feet in that little gap and fire their weapon through the barricade once the attacker stands still, destroying the placed charge and possibly killing the attacker.

If the gap at the base of the door was not there, attackers would be free to move around and setup their attack route without the defenders being able to know where they are.

Comment: So it does give an advantage to the defenders too. So that might be why.

Comment: Remember the reverse also holds true, the defenders could send out their drones themselves (out of universe explanation).

Comment: Yes, also consider that gameplay balance can be a legitimate reason lore wise, as the matches you are playing are generally considered to be inside a simulation (The reason you have friendly anti-terrorist groups fighting against and killing each other).

Comment: @HaiboLi in-game defenders do not have drones with the exception of one of the new Japanese Ops who has a flying drone.

Comment: My question came from that giving a free advantage towards the attackers, when it's the defenders setting it up. But now I see the defenders also get an advantage for it, so it's not a free advantage.

Comment: I have no proof, but I believe the larger gap was added for balance reasons, as [early pre-alpha footage](https://youtu.be/SGP2EZn121o?t=4m28s) shows there being no gap under the doors, but the drones were small enough to get under them anyways.

Comment: No, Echo one of the defenders has a drone he can send out the door, if it's an outside door only for a few seconds before signal is lost... basically like my old WiFi (**Edit: Didn't see Malco's comment**)